# Error when add row in php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<a class="checkModelButton" href="addrow.php">ADD ROW</a>
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Name</th> 
   </thead>
   <tboby id="model_row">
       <tr>Nokia N70</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And jQuery:

```
jQuery('.checkModelButton').click(function(){
   var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
   jQuery.ajax({
      type:'get',
      cache: false,
      url: url,
      success: function(html){
         jQuery('#model_row').html(html);
      }  
   });
});
```

in file addrow.php

```
<tr>Nokia N71</tr>
```

When I click on a tag is result is:

```
   <table>
       <thead>
           <th>Name</th> 
       </thead>
       <tboby id="model_row">
           <tr>Nokia N71</tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

How to fix it to result is:

```
   <table>
       <thead>
           <th>Name</th> 
       </thead>
       <tboby id="model_row">
           <tr>Nokia N70</tr>
           <tr>Nokia N71</tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.append()` OR `.appendTo()` instead of `.html()`

Like

```
success: function(html){
         jQuery('#model_row').append(html);
      }
```

OR

```
 success: function(html){
             jQuery(html).appendTo('#model_row');
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.html()` will overwrite the content.

You need to append it.

```
$('#model_row').append(html);
```

Comment: @AnkitGautam: I hadn't seen his html structure. I assumed it was a row which is why I used `insertAfter()`